# The best way to say that a certain fee is over the price?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

We have a certain CAP fee e.g. $1000. What is the best way to say that if you add e.g. $100 to this fee that it will be over the price.

"If you add this billing the CAP fee will be surmounted with ... dollars."
"If you add this billing the CAP fee will be overreached with ... dollars."

Or any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: The total price, including and additional $100 fee, is...

Comment: Simple solution and a good one. Might consider it. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean here? What is a CAP fee? Do you mean a _fee cap_, i.e., that $1,000 is the maximum you can pay in fees? And that if a particular billing is added, then the fee cap is exceeded, which must not happen? Or is a CAP fee a type of fee (something like [this](http://theticketinginstitute.com/cap-compliance-vendor-response/)?), and adding a billing just adds a certain amount to this CAP fee?

Comment: exceeded was the word I was looking for. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **surcharge**, a fee above and beyond the original amount.

*The CAP fee is $1000 plus an additional $100 **surcharge**.*

Answer (score 2):

If you add this billing the CAP fee will be **exceeded** by ... dollars.

Most synonyms of exceeded would work here - I started off with "breached", but exceeded feels better

Comment: You should mark this as the answer then - glad to help!